# ¿Qué opciones a la integración de datos existe usando bd no relacionales?

Tags: base-de-datos

Como dice el título, esa es mi pregunta. Así que MSSQL tiene SSIS, ¿qué opciones existen en el enfoque no relacional y de código abierto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una de las más populares en cuanto a open source es Pentaho. Ahora bien, son conceptos distintos una base de datos relacional, y una plataforma de BI, como el SSIS o Pentaho, las cuales pueden extraer data, transformar y cargala en otra base de datos (que puede ser relacional o no), un datawarehouse o un datamart.